# why my custom listview doesn´t increase when I add information to the arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, custom-lists

This code works for me, the thing is that when I try to add information to the list it appear like one row but if I try to add more information instead of appearing as another row the first one change to the new information. So why that happend?

The main class call Costo Productos .java:

```
public class Costo_Productos extends AppCompatActivity {


Button agregar_articulo_btn;

ListView ListaCompras;
private ArrayList<lista_compra_informacion> array;
private Lista_compra_adapter adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_costo__productos);

    agregar_articulo_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.agregar_btn);

    ListaCompras = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_de_compras);

    array = new ArrayList<lista_compra_informacion>();

    adapter = new Lista_compra_adapter(this, 
    R.layout.custom_lista_de_compras, array);

    char bandera='f';


    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    Bundle extras2 = intent2.getExtras();

    if (extras2!=null) {

        bandera = extras2.getChar("Bandera");

    }


    if(bandera=='v'){

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras!=null){

            String nombre = extras.getString("Nombre");
            String precio_producto = extras.getString("Precio");
            String cantidad = extras.getString("Cantidad");
            String total_pagar = extras.getString("Total");

            lista_compra_informacion informacion = new 
      lista_compra_informacion(nombre,cantidad,precio_producto,total_pagar);
            array.add(0,informacion);
            ListaCompras.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+nombre+" 
            "+precio_producto+" "+cantidad+" "+total_pagar, 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


}

public void buscar_articulos (View view){

    Intent lista_art = new Intent(this, lista_de_objetos.class);
    startActivity(lista_art);

}



}
```

Lista de compras informacion.java is the row of the list:

```
public class lista_compra_informacion {

public String Nombre;
public String Cantidad;
public String Precio;
public String Total;


public lista_compra_informacion(String Nombre, String Cantidad, String 
Precio, String Total){

    this.setNombre(Nombre);
    this.setCantidad(Cantidad);
    this.setPrecio(Precio);
    this.setTotal(Total);
}


public String getNombre() {
    return Nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    Nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCantidad() {
    return Cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(String cantidad) {
    Cantidad = cantidad;
}

public String getPrecio() {
    return Precio;
}

public void setPrecio(String precio) {
    Precio = precio;
}

public String getTotal() {
    return Total;
}

public void setTotal(String total) {
    Total = total;
}
}
```

Lista compra adapter .java  is the adapter of the list:

```
public class Lista_compra_adapter extends 
ArrayAdapter<lista_compra_informacion> {

private Activity context;
private int id;
ArrayList<lista_compra_informacion> array;


public Lista_compra_adapter(Activity context, int resource, 
ArrayList<lista_compra_informacion> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.id = resource;
    this.array = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView==null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(id, null);

    }

    TextView Nombre_txt = (TextView) 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_del_producto);
    TextView Cantidad_txt = (TextView) 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.cantidad);
    TextView Precio_txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.precio);
    TextView Total_txt = (TextView) 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.precio_total_producto);

    lista_compra_informacion informacion = array.get(position);
    Nombre_txt.setText(informacion.getNombre());
    Cantidad_txt.setText(informacion.getCantidad());
    Precio_txt.setText(informacion.getPrecio());
    Total_txt.setText(informacion.getTotal());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Paste the code where you're updating the list

Answer (score 0):

> So why that happend?

Because you are adding at most one element to the list by the block

```
if (extras!=null){

        String nombre = extras.getString("Nombre");
        String precio_producto = extras.getString("Precio");
        String cantidad = extras.getString("Cantidad");
        String total_pagar = extras.getString("Total");

        lista_compra_informacion informacion = new lista_compra_informacion(nombre,cantidad,precio_producto,total_pagar);
        array.add(0,informacion);
        ListaCompras.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+nombre+" 
        "+precio_producto+" "+cantidad+" "+total_pagar, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

As many elements you add the list as many elements are there in the listview as per your adapter implementation. So try to add more data elements in this block or in future execution of this activity. It's not like loading activity two times for two rows. Learn about activity life cycle. You see as many rows in the listview as many elements you add to the list of adapter followed by a call to `notifyDatasetChanged ()` during the life cycle of acivity.

Comment: I cant add more data  to the block because, the data have been gotten of a selected product in other listview every time the user access to it. my doubt is that I want to make  a custom listview of the data of products selected. there is any other way to increase the listview or a comand to the adapter to make other row??

Comment: Do you want to highlight the selected row of listview?

Comment: no!! I want to add products that people want from a list that contains all the products that a store has!

Comment: but I cant add more data in the block or what ever is that because there are new data everytime they select one product and I dont know which one they will select.  I took this code from internet but for mi it doesnt work and Im new in android.

Comment: I also see that the arraylist increase but there is an error while the secont row try to find Nombre.txt in the adapter class to set the text.

Comment: Probably you are looking for a list with multi selection. Then on pressing a button *(checkout)* you want to show all the selected items. Is that your case?

Comment: lets say like add values dinamically to a custom listview  like in this video!!  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NAavE5HDWk) is exactly the same but the add buttom and the edit texts are in other activity